# What is the probability of getting license plate 888-UUU

Tags: probability

I saw the license plate 888-UUU the other day and wondered what the probability was a plate with 3 of the same number and letter.  Our states license plate format is 3 numbers and 3 alphabetic characters.

Comment: Are any digits or characters banned in certain places? Are any _words_ banned?

Comment: If there are no constraints on characters/digits, then it would just be $10^{-3}26^{-3}$ would it not? Edit: this was for probability of 888-UUU specifically.

Comment: Probably 0, as they probably don't make any licenses like that unless they are vanities.  But as you need to digits/numbers to be the same as the first it woulld be $\frac {1}{10^226^2}$.

Comment: yep I was mainly wondering the odds of getting a plate with 3 of the same number and letter.  So 222-HHH, 777-AAA, etc, would all be valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there are assumptions in this game (as always with applications of probability theory to reality). We assume that all for the first three digits all of the numbers $\{0,\dots, 9\}$ are equally likely (and independent), and the same for the three characters chosen from $\{A,\dots, Z\}$.

We want to know the probability that we obtain a set of three identical letters when uniformly and randomly chose from a set of $n$ elements. The total number of results is given by $n^3$. Obtaining three identical elements, means that the first element can be anything (n possibilities), while the rest is fixed. Thus, we have
$$P(\text{three same}) = \frac{n}{n^3} = \frac{1}{n^2}\;.$$

In you case, we have $n=10$ for the numbers and $n=26$ for the characters, thus the result reads
$$P = \frac{1}{10^2}\cdot \frac{1}{26^2} \;.$$

Comment: Could a plate **000-XXX** exist ?